# Symfony 3 route annotations

Tags: php, symfony

Explain me please why this order of route annotations give me 301 redirect, but reverse order well works. Difference between two routes is only a slash.

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class GenusController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/genus/");
     */
    public function showAction2()
    {
        return $this->render('/genus/show.html.twig', ['name' => 'test1']);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/genus");
     */
    public function showAction($genusName = 'test2')
    {
        $templating = $this->container->get('templating');
        $html = $templating->render('/genus/show.html.twig', ['name' => $genusName]);

        return new Response($html);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your actual code in the question rather than a link to an image.

Comment: Depends on which route gets loaded first. Since there is nothing after the `/`, then the router is matching to the first in the list gets returned.

Comment: Forgot to mention, it's about the route "/genus" - 301 to "/genus/"

Comment: If you are using apache, then your htaccess also has something to do with it as well. `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$` `RewriteRule ^app\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: No, I've used php build-in server for this example.